# Dual Boot Ubuntu on a laptop with Hard Drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I look online and try several approaches but so far no luck, I have a laptop with 2 hard drive

1. HD 1 normal laptop slot with Windows 2
2. HD 2 DVD/CD ROM using caddy (this where I want ubuntu install)

I install ubuntu on HD 2 GNOME 16.4.2 following [this steps](http://linuxbsdos.com/2014/05/31/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-windows-7-on-a-pc-with-2-hdds-and-uefi-firmware/) but the laptop does not recognize the second boot.

can this be done?
[Result.txt](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24411318/)

Comment: is newer laptop acer aspire e-15 that support UEIF

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from a Linux emergency disk (like the Ubuntu installer in "try before installing" mode). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: I ran the scrip please see file attached

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your installation is quite odd. Some key points from the Boot Info Script output:

- `/dev/sda` uses the [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table). This is usually associated with EFI-mode booting.
- `/dev/sdb` uses the older [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partitioning system. This is usually associated with BIOS-mode booting.
- `/dev/sdb`'s MBR has a copy of the Windows boot loader.
- The main Windows installation is on `/dev/sda`.
- `/dev/sda1` is an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) and it looks like it holds a copy of GRUB, which is Ubuntu's boot loader.
- The main Ubuntu installation is on `/dev/sdb`.

Thus, it looks like you've got a weird setup in which a BIOS-mode boot loader on `/dev/sdb` boots Windows from the GPT `/dev/sda`, and an EFI-mode boot loader on `/dev/sda` boots Ubuntu from the MBR `/dev/sdb`. I'm puzzled about how it got into this configuration, since I'd expect each OS's installer to complain quite loudly and refuse to contort itself into such a bizarre configuration; but obviously, it's somehow gotten configured in this way, and it sounds like Windows *is* booting.

My initial reaction to this setup is to advise you to wipe it out and start from scratch, re-installing *both* OSes in a more sensible way. If you're willing to do so, I recommend going with GPT and EFI-mode booting exclusively. The following pages will help you get this set up in a more reasonable way:

- **[Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)** -- This page describes the theory behind EFI-mode booting.
- **[My page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)** -- This page is a more practical introduction to EFI-mode booting than Adam Williamson's blog.
- **[My page on the CSM](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)** -- This page covers the CSM, including when it's useful and when it's not. If you follow my advice, you'd want to *disable* your CSM so it doesn't complicate things.

If you can't re-install everything, it's much trickier. I presume that you'd want to preserve Windows, since Ubuntu is a fresh installation; but the Windows boot path is so strange (being both cross-disk and involving an MBR/BIOS boot loader that boots an installation from a different GPT disk) that any procedure you follow runs a serious risk of rendering Windows unbootable. If you're willing to take that risk, I recommend:

1. Completely back up your Windows installation, or at least your important user data; there's a significant chance that you'll have to restore a backup if you follow the below procedure.
2. Boot the Ubuntu installer *in BIOS mode* (see my CSM page, above, for tips on how to do this). Tell it you want to try Ubuntu without installing.
3. Using GParted, shrink a partition on `/dev/sda` by 1MiB and create a [BIOS Boot Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_boot_partition) in its place. (See [here](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd) for basic GParted usage instructions.)
4. Launch the Ubuntu installer using the icon in the bar to the left of the screen.
5. Tell the installer to install to the existing partitions on `/dev/sdb`.
6. Tell the installer to install the boot loader to `/dev/sda`.
7. Finish the installation.

With any luck, the system will boot into GRUB, which will then enable you to launch either Windows or Ubuntu. If you're unlucky, though, it might not work at all, or you might be able to boot one OS but not the other. If you find that the system continues to boot straight to Windows, adjusting the boot order in your computer's firmware setup utility may fix the problem.

---

***EDIT:*** Egrimo's suggestion to use rEFInd *might* be another way around the problem, but it's not as easy as just installing rEFInd. You'd need to adjust its `scanfor` line, as noted in my comment to Egrimo's answer. I *strongly* recommend testing it from a USB flash drive before attempting to install rEFInd to the hard disk, given the delicate nature of the current installation.

Comment: Rod Thanks for the detail explanation, I think I should get a price for such complex setup and still boot on Windows.  Any how I don't have any problem in redo both OSes, and probably that are the step that I'm going to take. Let you how it goes later this week.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases Refind Bootloader will see both operating systems and it workes through macOS, Windows and Linux.

Comment: rEFInd *might* help, but only if it's reconfigured to support both EFI-mode and BIOS-mode booting by uncommenting `scanfor` and adding `hdbios` to its options in `refind.conf`. I strongly recommend testing this with the CD-R version of rEFInd before attempting an install to the hard disk. A fresh re-install of everything in EFI mode would be a cleaner solution, but if rEFInd can get the current setup to boot, using it would be less of a hassle.

Answer (score -1):

You can but you must format your second HD that you are installing UBUNTU on to FAT32, then from your Bios Boot order choose the second HD